# software to automatically record telephone calls (landline)

Tags: audio, mp3, recording, telephony

I'm looking for some software which will record all calls made or received on my landline telephone. Any suggestions? I want to keep a record of all calls saved on my computer as MP3 or some other kind of compressed audio file. (Note: It's perfectly legal in my country to do this. I checked with my lawyer.) Thanks!

**Also: This question is NOT a duplicate. Please don't close it. All of the other threads on this subject deal with Skype or cell phones, whereas I'm looking to record my LANDLINE!**

Comment: How do you want to connect the audio to the PC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this, not free

http://www.sound-snooper.com/en/features.php

.

Audacity says it does sound activated recording, its free

http://audacity.sourceforge.net/